# PHP gettext() - putenv and setlocale

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, locale, gettext

I see most of the examples are using something like:

```
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");
echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");
```

If I only want to get message translation done, I've tried that only `putenv` is needed, and I don't need to the functions provided by `setlocale` such as time, MONETARY etc.

So, it is safe to ignore the `setlocale`?

Answer (score 2):

No it is required.

You can of course do `setlocale(LC_ALL, '');` as other answer is suggesting but this will just make it fall back to environmental variable set by `putenv` a line above.

What can be in fact removed is `putenv` call. At least for me the following snippet is still returning German translation:

```
putenv('LC_ALL=en_US');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");
echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");
```

Another good thing you can use `setlocale` for is checking if given locale is actually installed in the system. E.g.:

```
if (false === setlocale(LC_ALL, $localeCode)) {
    throw new LocaleNotSupportedException(sprintf('Locale "%s" is not installed in the system.', $localeCode));
}

echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");
```

And also there's no need go set locale before binding a domain. You can also do it anytime after.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would be safe in not including it.

> If locale is NULL or the empty string "", the locale names will be set
> from the values of environment variables with the same names as the
> above categories, or from "LANG".

Info: https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setlocale.php